# How to remove "/upload" in opencart url?

Tags: php, .htaccess, opencart-3

Am using Opencart(Version 3) for my store. My domain url will be like **www.something.com**. 
Is it possible that in the htaccess or some other way to change it from **www.something.com/upload/**  to **www.something.com**.Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Your question is unclear.